# How to use OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of in .netframework API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I have 2 APIs and I wanted to use OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow to generate the token in API1 and Authorize to API2 with  the generated token.

I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#middle-tier-access-token-request and I was able to generate the token.
I use this following parameters:

```
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
client_id:xxxxx
client_secret:xxxxxx
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
```

But I don't know how to authenticate to my API2 with that token and get the user and what are the next steps. My API to uses .netframework app.

I created OwinStartup and added UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication

```
 app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Tenant = "xxxxxxxxxx",// Azure tenant Id
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    SaveSigninToken = true,
                    ValidAudience = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
                }
            });
```

and added Authorize attribute into my controller. but when I called the get endpoint to that controller, it gave me an error saying:
Authorization has been denied for this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API A I was using a wrong scope to generate token. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#middle-tier-access-token-request

Answer (score 1):

You need to request two tokens, one is the access token of **API A**, and the other is the access token of **API B** obtained using the access token of API A as a parameter.

The document you refer to is based on the api A access token you have obtained, and there are [instructions in the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#protocol-diagram).

First, you need to use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or other login flow  to obtain the access token of api A:

[image]

Then use the access token of API A as a parameter to obtain the access token of API B.

[image]

Comment: I've already done that part in API A and I have the token. but I when I passed the access token as Authorization(Bearer ) header to API B I get an error.
Authorization has been denied for this request. I added app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication in API B statup.cs class. but didn't helped